# Can you pass custom data in an intent bundle and get them back in OnActivityResult?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using the camera intent to take a picture that I wish to attach to a report.

I have the report id which currently I am storing in a peristent fragment, and when I get the result use it to see what to attach the photograph to.

Is there a way to add some extras to the intent I launch that takes the photograph and then when `OnActivityResult` fires retrieve them?

edit:
as an example here is something I would like to be able to do:

```
val i = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
i.putExtra(REPORT_ID,324) //or something like this????
startActivityForResult(i,REQUEST);
```

and after this

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    val image: Bitmap? = data?.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap?
    val reportId = ?????
}
```

Comment: Why you want to send data from intent. While you are launching intent and receiving intent in same activity.

Comment: because there may be a configuration change (which in theory , the retained fragment should handle) and because the user may open any number of external intents at the same time, so I wish to know what triggered it

Comment: Its not possible for camera intent or may be for all intent, as your intent to launch camera and camera's intent to give you result are diffrent. And camera intent will give you picture uri in its extras.

Comment: yeah I was afraid this was the case :( , thank you

Comment: You sholud do something for onConfigurationChange for your activity and fragment

Comment: no I have handled that, all my data is stored in a fragment that retains its instance state, I'm just being a bit paranoid I guess, trying to catch a case where the user manages to launch multiple external intents at the same time, which in theory I have blocked, but I like to be thorough

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass custom data through implementation parcelable. But through bundle don't recommend pass big data like an image. Better whey is passing image URI to bundel.

Comment: my problem is not how to pass custom data, my problem is that I wish to send data to an intent I do not control and get them back when the intent finishes